# Custom Hotkey Toggle Initialization

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts/4209612#4209612) old stack overflow answer (referring to [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/May/msg00200.html/wiki/wiki.jsp?pageName=FAQ_Front_ends) even older page) it is shown how to make custom hotkeys by modifying the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr`.

Some examples are given, a hotkey to quit the kernel is extremely useful and is achieved by adding:

```
   Item[KeyEvent["q", Modifiers -> {Control, Option}],
           FrontEndExecute[
                   FrontEndToken[
                            SelectedNotebook[ ],
                            "EvaluatorQuit",
                            Automatic
                   ]
           ]
   ]
```

However, the other example to toggle the initialization cell status:

```
  Item[KeyEvent["i", Modifiers -> {Command, Control}],
           FrontEndExecute[
                   FrontEndToken[
                           SelectedNotebook[ ],
                           "InitializationCell",
                           "Toggle"
                   ]
           ]
   ]
```

does not work for me (version 11.01 on Mac).
It does turn a selected cell into an initialization cell, but if it already was one, it does not turn it off again.

Is there a way to modify this to work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In M11.3+, use the following instead:

```
Item[
    KeyEvent["i", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}],
    FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEnd`SetOptions[FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[], InitializationCell->Toggle]
    ]
]
```

For earlier versions, use:

```
Item[
    KeyEvent["i", Modifiers -> {Control, Command}],
    FrontEndExecute[
        FrontEnd`SetOptions[
            FrontEnd`NotebookSelection[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[]],
            InitializationCell->Toggle
        ]
    ]
]
```

Also, you mention modifying `KeyEventTranslations.tr`. It is safer to instead copy `KeyEventTranslations.tr` to the following directory (create the directory if necessary):

```
FileNameJoin[
    {$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","TextResources","Macintosh"}
]
```

and then modify the copy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however this crashes my Mathematica. Also copying the file to that location and modifying the copy (restoring the original one to the original version) the quit kernel command doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Crashes usually indicate syntax errors. Both hot keys work for me. Start with something simple. Copy the file exactly, and change the hotkey for Ctrl-6 to "Subscript" instead of "Superscript". Quit Mathematica and restart. Has the hotkey changed?

Comment: It hasn't changed. I'm supposed to leave the one at `$InstallationDirectory` (with same subfolders) as the original, copy that to `$UserBaseDirectory/..` and modify only the latter right? (for this latter location I had to create the folders TextResources/Macintosh myself)

Comment: What version are  you using?

Comment: "11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)", running on a new MacBook Pro (I'm trying to set these hotkeys up Touch Bar buttons)

Comment: I've accidentally solved the original problem: control+8 already toggles initialization cells, although I don't see this in the file. The quit kernel command now also works in the copied file in the `$UserBaseDirectory`, however the superscript to subscript still does not.

Comment: Thanks, I just tested the version for earlier versions and it works. Although apparently there already was the control+8 hotkey. Is all this documented somewhere?